# How to solve the problem of "Cast int64 to string is not supported"?

Tags: python, keras

I am using the following code but getting the error of `"Cast int64 to string is not supported"` and `"UnimplementedError: Exception encountered when calling layer "string_lookup_20" (type StringLookup)."`

How may I solve it? where the error is appears by the following line of code:

```
labels = label_processor(labels[..., None]).numpy()

def prepare_all_videos(df, root_dir):
    num_samples = len(df)
    video_paths = df["video_name"].values.tolist()
    labels = df["tag"].values
    print(type(labels))
    labels = label_processor(labels[..., None]).numpy()
    print(type(labels))

    # `frame_masks` and `frame_features` are what we will feed to our sequence model.
    # `frame_masks` will contain a bunch of booleans denoting if a timestep is
    # masked with padding or not.
    frame_masks = np.zeros(shape=(num_samples, MAX_SEQ_LENGTH), dtype="bool")
    frame_features = np.zeros(
        shape=(num_samples, MAX_SEQ_LENGTH, NUM_FEATURES), dtype="float32"
    )

    # For each video.
    for idx, path in enumerate(video_paths):
        # Gather all its frames and add a batch dimension.
        frames = load_video(os.path.join(root_dir, path))
        frames = frames[None, ...]

        # Initialize placeholders to store the masks and features of the current video.
        temp_frame_mask = np.zeros(shape=(1, MAX_SEQ_LENGTH,), dtype="bool")
        temp_frame_features = np.zeros(
            shape=(1, MAX_SEQ_LENGTH, NUM_FEATURES), dtype="float32"
        )

        # Extract features from the frames of the current video.
        for i, batch in enumerate(frames):
            video_length = batch.shape[0]
            length = min(MAX_SEQ_LENGTH, video_length)
            for j in range(length):
                temp_frame_features[i, j, :] = feature_extractor.predict(
                    batch[None, j, :]
                )
            temp_frame_mask[i, :length] = 1  # 1 = not masked, 0 = masked

        frame_features[idx,] = temp_frame_features.squeeze()
        frame_masks[idx,] = temp_frame_mask.squeeze()

    return (frame_features, frame_masks), labels


train_data, train_labels = prepare_all_videos(train_df, "train")
test_data, test_labels = prepare_all_videos(test_df, "test")

print(f"Frame features in train set: {train_data[0].shape}")
print(f"Frame masks in train set: {train_data[1].shape}")
```

Comment: Hey.. Can you please check whether the type of your labels are integers not strings.

Comment: Also, make sure about the shape of your tensors, https://stackoverflow.com/a/70675580/6072570